# Install a software remotely using cmd

Tags: windows, installation, command-line

I have the administrator right. I want to install a software(.exe) in all computers in my network using cmd (Command line) from my computer. I am using Windows 7. I have done some researches but I am unable to figure it out. Please help me. Please note that i do not want to install any other software to do that. Thank you for your help:)

well I found that we can use misexec.exe-but i am unable to use that because i don't know the syntax.

All my computers are connected to a hub.

All computers are using Windows 7.

Comment: assuming you're using a domain setup, just set up a group policy for such things.

Comment: Please post more information: 1. examples of tutorials you've found. 2. The organisation of computers on your network, e.g. operating systems, configurations

Comment: Do you know if the software you want to install even supports unattended installation?